# Convert String to Int without int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement `add2strings`, `sub2strings`, `mult2strings` functions in Python. They're all very easy if you just do `int(string)`, but I want to do them without that and without importing another cheating thing like `Decimal`. My current idea is to use `bytes`.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I am *very* curious to know why you want to do this.

Comment: You could split string to get chars and then you can compare char with `"0"` to get digit `0`, etc.

Comment: Coding practice. And I'm liking Python a lot more than C/C++ ATM.

Comment: @furas ah interesting idea! I suppose that would work.

Comment: I liked this kind of challenges when I was using C :)

Comment: I'm going to do your method furas. It makes me feel slightly better about doing this in Python instead of C.

Comment: I did this once in Pascal many years ago -- It's both non-trivial and very slow :)

Comment: This would be much better on http://CodeGolf.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refer to a basic `atoi` in C:

```c
int myAtoi(char *str)
{
    int res = 0; // Initialize result

    // Iterate through all characters of input string and update result
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        res = res*10 + str[i] - '0';

    // return result.
    return res;
}
```

Which translates into the Python:

```py
def atoi(s):
    rtr=0
    for c in s:
        rtr=rtr*10 + ord(c) - ord('0')

    return rtr
```

Test it:

```
>>> atoi('123456789')
123456789
```

If you want to accommodate an optional sign and whitespace the way that `int` does:

```py
def atoi(s):
    rtr, sign=0, 1
    s=s.strip()
    if s[0] in '+-':
        sc, s=s[0], s[1:]
        if sc=='-':
            sign=-1

    for c in s:
        rtr=rtr*10 + ord(c) - ord('0')

    return sign*rtr
```

Now add exceptions and you are there!

Comment: Nice idea, didn't realize I can just generalize the problems by making an atoi, doing arithmetic and then using an itoa. I was thinking hardware and planning on using carry bits.

Comment: Of course you would need to modify to handle whitespace and an optional + or - and the start of the string, but both are trivial to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is really inefficient but:

```
>>> zero = ord("0")
>>> s = "1234"
>>> sum([x * 10**i for i, x in enumerate(map(lambda x: x - zero, map(ord, s))[::-1])])
1234
```

This is slightly better:

```
>>>> sum([x * 10**i for i, x in enumerate([ord(x) - zero for x in s[::-1]])])
1234

>>> atoi = lambda s: sum([x * 10**i for i, x in enumerate([ord(x) - zero for x in s[::-1]])])
>>> atoi("1234")
1234
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
def str_to_int(input_str):
    if input_str[0] == "-":
        is_negative = True
        input_str = input_str[1:]
    else:
        is_negative = False

    output_int = 0

    for i in input_str:
        output_int = output_int * 10 + ord(i) - ord("0")

    if is_negative:
        output_int *= -1

    return output_int
```

```
print(str_to_int("123"))
print(str_to_int("-123"))
```

output:

```
123
-123
```

Answer (score 1):

[What about just iterating through all the integers, *converting them to strings* and comparing strings?](http://codepad.org/xTbLLXBJ)

```
import exceptions
MAX_INT  = 1000
MIN_INT = -1000

def str2int(s):
  for i in range(MIN_INT,MAX_INT):
    if s == str(i):
      return i
  raise exceptions.OverflowError

def add2strings(s,t):
  return str(str2int(s)+str2int(t))

print add2strings("170","-300")
print add2strings("170","-1001")
```

This gives:

```
"-170"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 15, in <module>
    print add2strings("170","-1001")
  Line 12, in add2strings
    return str(str2int(s)+str2int(t))
  Line 9, in str2int
    raise exceptions.OverflowError
OverflowError
```

Comment: Go home, you're drunk.

Comment: You can't tell me when to code and *hic* when not to code. *hic* Thats why is *free* maaaaan... *free as in beer*.